# Using Roman page numbering in the abstract environment in the case of the Arabic language

Tags: page-numbering, abstract

In the code below, I want as output the summary in Arabic with the Roman page numbering, but the page numbering is displayed in Arabic.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm] {geometry}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
\begin{abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain}%To display page number.
\setcounter{page}{5}
ملخص بالعربية
\end{abstract}
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Processing (via `pdflatex`) your MWE produces  the error `\end occured inside a group at level `. This may be part of your problem.

Comment: No, it's not part of my problem. @Peter Wilson